# How to extract just the visualization data from the solidworks files .sldprt and .sldasm in a standalone application?

Tags: parsing, cad, solidworks

Maybe like converting .sldprt to stl or step file outside solidworks. I dont want to create this using a plugin for solidworks..

I know that visualization data is public but the original geometry and brep data is stored in proprietary format of solidworks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Varun,

SolidWorks provides source code of the project named display-lists that provide functionality to extract tesselation info from SW files without the SW software itself. Check it out here: https://forum.solidworks.com/docs/DOC-2323

Comment: Thanks Andrey!!! I am unable to compile this code.. It requires implodei.lib. Which I believe is not available for download.. It requires this file to un-compress the solidworks files.. So cant manage without it..  It seems to be part of pkware sdk for windows.. But I am not sure.. Pkware doesnt even mention the cost of this sdk for windows..

Comment: Right, it's part of pkzip. I didn't know that it's not free.

Comment: I am still trying to get hold of those libraries to compile the display-lists project.. Would you know if feature tree/assembly hierarchy can also be extracted from solidworks files. Does display list project have such a capability?

Comment: Feature tree - no; assembly hierarchy - yes.

Comment: The link into the forum no longer works. Update please!